# can i provide explicit gradients/hessians to pytorch/keras to accelerate learning?

Tags: keras, pytorch

Same as questions. I think my current pytorch/keras does not train mse/ other custom loss function well. Is there a way that I can input gradient/hessian (diagonal) explicitly. To make it train better?

Comment: You can always access the network's parameters and change the data as you wish. Will this answer your question or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Can you post an example of where you believe pytorch is incorrectly computing the gradient? This would be quite surprising in general. I guess if you have a custom loss function it may be unstable and maybe the floating point errors are compounding but in such case I doubt a more precise estimate of the gradient is the solution. One option if you choose to persue it is to make your loss into a [`autograd.Function`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html) and provide an explicit `backward` method.